# Django returns a strange Internal Server Error even though DEBUG=True

Tags: python, django, apache, postgresql, ubuntu

I have a very strange situation guys. Django's DEBUG is equal to True, but when I run a certain specific script it returns the below error, as opposed to Django's standard debug output:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, ababab@gmail.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at ababab.com Port 80
```

Why could this be happening? I noticed when I remove the below code, I get no errors. The view is:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

def index():
    mostViewed = ProfileVisits.objects.filter(timestamp__gt = datetime.now() - timedelta(7))[0]
    return HttpResponse(mostViewed)
```

I noticed that when I insert the row `mostViewed = len(mostViewed)` right before the bottom row, I get an output of `1` which is expected. Also I noticed there are no errors when I iterate through *mostViewed* and add it to a list.

Anything that would point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: that looks like apache error not django, are you sure `debug=True`? check out your apache error logs

Comment: you are not sending the `request` object as a parameter to the `index` method. use `return render()` instead

Comment: Also, remove `import datetime` at the beginning

Comment: @karthikr, that using return render() did not solve the problem :/

Comment: and how about the other issues i have mentioned ?

Comment: debug definitely equals True and I removed import datetime as well.

Comment: and did you change to `def index(request)` ? Then restart the server

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be wrapping a query set in HttpResponse. Take a look at the Django view docs, where there are lots of usage examples: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/views/